# extracting node information

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping

Using the XML library, I have parsed a web page

```
basicInfo <- htmlParse(myURL, isURL = TRUE)
```

the relevant section of which is

```
<div class="col-left"><h1 class="tourney-name">Price Cutter Charity Championship Pres'd         by Dr Pep</h1><img class="tour-logo" alt="Nationwide Tour" src="http://a.espncdn.com/i/golf/leaderboard11/logo-nationwide-tour.png"/></div>
```

I can manage to extract the tournament name

```
tourney <- xpathSApply(basicInfo, "//*/div[@class='col-left']", xmlValue)
```

but also wish to know the tour it is from using the alt tag. In this case I want to get the result "Nationwide Tour"

TIA and apologies for scrolling required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know R but I'm pretty good with XPath

Try this:

```
tourney_name <- xpathSApply(basicInfo, "//*/div[@class='col-left']/h1/text()", xmlValue)
tourney_loc <- xpathSApply(basicInfo, "//*/div[@class='col-left']/img/@alt", xmlValue)
```

Note the use of "@" to extract attributes and text() to extract text nodes (looks like R did this automatically), my revised tourney_name xpath should do the same thing, but it is more clear which part is being extracted.

Comment: Mark. Looks like that will do the trick. Just need to leave out the xmlValue parameter for the alt attribute on the tourney_loc